# Add multiple guests to google calendar event using script from google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am using a form built on google sheets that feeds a database. I want to add events to the calendar based on this data, and include guests of my team to invite to this events according to a checkbox selection. Sometimes I will invite none up to 10 guests to each event.

This is the code

```
function salvarAgenda(){

 var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
 var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Formulario"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet

 var ativarAgenda = shUserForm.getRange("I11").getValue();

 if (ativarAgenda == false) {return}

 else {

 shUserForm.getRange("I11").setValue(false);


 var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("BancoDeDados"); ////delcare a variable and set with the Database worksheet
 var convidados = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Convidados");
 var suporte = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Suporte");
 var agendaID = suporte.getRange("E2").getValue();
 var agenda = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById(agendaID);

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features
 var response = ui.alert("Confirmar", 'Deseja registrar os dados da reserva no calendário?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  if (response == ui.Button.NO) // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects No
   {return;//exit from this function
  } 

  else {

   var str = shUserForm.getRange("G23").getValue();
   var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

   for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     var rowValue = values[i]; //declaraing a variable and storing the value

     //checking the first value of the record is equal to search item
      if (rowValue[27] == str) {

        var title = rowValue[21]; //title
        var chegada = rowValue[28]; //check-in
        var saida = rowValue[29]; //check-out
        var descricao = rowValue[22]; //description
       
        var numeroDeConvidados = convidados.getLastRow()-1;
        
        var guestA = convidados.getRange("B2").getValue();
        var guestB= convidados.getRange("B3").getValue();
        var guestC = convidados.getRange("B4").getValue();
        var guestD = convidados.getRange("B5").getValue();
        var guestE = convidados.getRange("B6").getValue();
        var guestF = convidados.getRange("B7").getValue();
        var guestG = convidados.getRange("B8").getValue();
        var guestH = convidados.getRange("B9").getValue();
        var guestI = convidados.getRange("B10").getValue();
        var guestJ = convidados.getRange("B11").getValue();


        if (numeroDeConvidados == ""){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 1){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 2){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 3){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 4){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 5){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 6){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).addGuest(guestF).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 7){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).addGuest(guestF).addGuest(guestG).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 8){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).addGuest(guestF).addGuest(guestG).addGuest(guestH).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 9){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).addGuest(guestF).addGuest(guestG).addGuest(guestH).addGuest(guestI).setColor('3');};
        if (numeroDeConvidados == 10){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).addGuest(guestA).addGuest(guestB).addGuest(guestC).addGuest(guestD).addGuest(guestE).addGuest(guestF).addGuest(guestG).addGuest(guestH).addGuest(guestI).addGuest(guestJ).setColor('3');};
        
      }
    }
  }
 }

  shUserForm.hideColumns(8,3);
  shUserForm.getRange("G16").setValue(false);

 ui.alert('Registro salvo com sucesso na agenda');
```

This was the way I could get through, as every time will be different guests. My skills on writing codes are very limited, so I would appreciate if someone could know a better way get the job done.

I am using a onEdit trigger to run the script. As I am the user that is developing the script, I am afraid that when other editor user tries to run it, he won´t have permissions for that. Any tips? Thank you very much.

Comment: First try to get each of these values `var guestA = convidados.getRange("B2").getValue();` into an array so that you can use array method like forEach or reduce to accomplish the task in a loop and that way you can determine the number of guests via array.length.

Comment: Also the assignment for those values can be much simpler with the use of a [destructed assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: You can avoid the current approach of hardcoding each loop which starts with this line `if (numeroDeConvidados == ""){ agenda.createEvent(title, chegada,saida).setDescription(descricao).setColor('3');};` by getting the guest information in a loop.  All of this may be a bit challenging for you but when you return you should be able to provide an [mcve] that we can use to assist you further.